# NodeJs response client's url request to another

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm managing one kind of client request starts from '/js/' which means root folder on server side or maybe will be located in '/public/js/' for further use. 
Okay, the problem is I got this message:

```
//server side
GET /js/socket.io/socket.io.js 304 7ms  

// client side 
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined     
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

[x] source

```
// index.html
<script src="/js/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

// app.js   
app.get('/js/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + req.url.substr('/js'.length));
});
```

But it does work when I change to fixed path.

[o] source

```
// index.html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

// app.js   
app.get('/socket.io/socket.io.js', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/socket.io/socket.io.js');
});
```

It's kind of weird, isn't it? Could anybody figure out where is wrong plz.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's your exact problem with that response?

A `304` status code means `Not modified`, meaning that your browser can used the cached version of `/js/socket.io/socket.io.js` instead of the server having to send it to the browser again (therefore, saving bandwidth).

Comment: the error appears in client side is following:

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined 

but the successful case doesn't have the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use the server version of `socket.io.js` in the client. `socket.io` installs its own handler for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` so you don't have to create a handler for that in your server side code (see http://socket.io/#how-to-use)

Comment: Thanks, I've removed this handler and works. But I'm still curious the first case actually send the file located in /socket.io/socket.io.js on server side. That means it's the same way as the second case, isn't it ?

Comment: It's not the same. The first `socket.io.js` file, which gives you the errors, is the part of socket.io which is meant to run on the server only, and not in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

When you require socket.io in your application, it sets a handler to intercept requests for `/socket.io/socket.io.js` ([source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/0d5200ed696f4dc442efd00ab5d09b004294b762/lib/index.js#L145)). That is why the second example works.

In fact, you can remove these lines in `app.js`:

```
app.get('/socket.io/socket.io.js', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/socket.io/socket.io.js');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but the correct answer belongs to the first article although your way is correct as well. Hope you don't mind.